# How to handler url routing in asp.net webforms with similar path but multiple Page Handlers

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, routes, url-routing

Different urls with different page handlers are not working properly as it always take first route handler from global.asax file.

```
Page_ID     Page_Name               Page_url                                    Page_Handler        Parent_Page_ID
1           Home                    home                                        index.aspx              0               
2           Personal                personal                                    Personal.aspx           0               
3           Accounts & Deposits     personal/acounts-deposit                    Personal.aspx           2               
4           Current Account         personal/acounts-deposit/current-account    Personal.aspx           3               
5           Current Gold Accounts   personal/acounts-deposit/gold-account       gold-account.aspx       3               
6           Easy Saver              personal/acounts-deposit/easy-saaver-ac     Personal.aspx           3               
7           Fixed Deposits          personal/acounts-deposit/fixed-account      fixed-account.aspx      3               
8           Loans                   loans                                       loans.aspx              0               
9           Personal Loans          loans/personal-loans                        loans.aspx              8               
10          car Loans               car-loans                                   car-loan.aspx           8
```

In my `Menu_Table` I can identify page by `Page_url` as it is unique.

```
    routes.MapPageRoute("Personal_Route", "en/{*path}", "~/personal.aspx", false,
        new RouteValueDictionary {
                    { "path", "Page-not-found" },{ "PageName", "Page-not-found" }
                });


    routes.MapPageRoute("Personal_Route2", "en/{*path}", "~/gold-account.aspx", false,
        new RouteValueDictionary {
                    { "path", "Page-not-found" },{ "PageName", "Page-not-found" }
                });

    routes.MapPageRoute("Personal_Route2", "en/{*path}", "~/fixed-account.aspx", false,
        new RouteValueDictionary {
                    { "path", "Page-not-found" },{ "PageName", "Page-not-found" }
                });
```

Above route code always use personal.aspx as handler for all url by default

I have tried for quite some time but I am not able to get it right. I would appreciate help in this regard so that each page is handled by it correct page handler based on `Page_url`

I want page to be handled by there page handler

```
www.abc.com/personal  ----  (Personal.aspx)
www.abc.com/personal/acounts-deposits -----(Personal.aspx)
www.abc.com/personal/acounts-deposits/current-account -----(Personal.aspx)
www.abc.com/personal/acounts-deposits/current-gold-account ----- (gold-account.aspx)
www.abc.com/personal/acounts-deposits/easy-saver-ac -----(Personal.aspx)
www.abc.com/personal/acounts-deposits/fixed-account ----- (fixed-account.aspx(
www.abc.com/loans ----- (loans.aspx) 
www.abc.com/loans/personal-loans ----- (loans.aspx)
www.abc.com/loans/car-loans ----- (car-loan.aspx)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify the routeUrl argument more specific.

Please take a look at two msdn pages, if you haven't already:

1. [RouteCollection.MapPageRoute Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd784594%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
2. [Walkthrough: Using ASP.NET Routing in a Web Forms Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd329551.aspx)
3. [How to: Define Routes for Web Forms Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668177%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)